# Edubuntu: can not login, it just keeps blinking

Tags: 12.04, edubuntu

I just installed a fresh Edubuntu 12.04.

It asked me to select which mode to enter. I selected Edubuntu "normal mode" and after that nothing appeared on the screen, but screen kept on blinking.  This continued for 15 minutes.

I have AMD RADEON as graphic card.

I can, however, login to edubuntu using recovery mode and pressing "resume boot" option.

How can I resolve this problem?